# Is there any way to undo 'undo checkout'?

Tags: versioning, check-out, check-in

Can you get those changes back in any way (powershell, etc.) or are they completely gone?

Comment: please add more details to elaborate the question, right now unclear what is your asking.

Comment: this is what you looking for https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Undo-check-out-and-discard-changes-to-a-file-43723b82-da85-4cbd-b1e7-b271036f824f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you have version control enabled - and you have saved at least once, then you can access that version from the version menu and restore it.

If you are not using version control - then the answer is no, you can not "undo" the undo.  The changes are unfortunately lost.